# Non-recursive file type excluding

Tags: sublimetext3

What I need:

```
scripts/app/file.js // show
scripts/file.js // ignore
```

What Sublime does instead:

```
scripts/app/file.js // ignore
scripts/file.js // ignore
```

My config:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": [
    "scripts/*.js" // works for Git but not for Sublime
]
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I've recently [written about how the exclude and include patterns work/don't work on the ST3 forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-project-file-folder-exclude-patterns/19997/2), which may help you.

Comment: @KeithHall so this probably doesn't work at all?

Comment: unless you can find a way to use `file_include_patterns` to match all your wanted files, unfortunately not I believe